# Using lm() for linear regression in long vs wide format

Tags: r, statistics

I have data in long format, one observation per row. The data was collected over 4 time periods and the time periods are stored in the stage variable: baseline, prefunded, postfunded, consequent.

I would like to run a linear regression for posemo on agency using lm() within each time period, so something like:

```r
lm(posemo_baseline ~ agency_baseline, data = x)
lm(posemo_prefunded ~ agency_prefunded, data = x)
etc...
```

Should I use reshaper or spread() to convert this to wide format with new columns for posemo_baseline, posemo_prefunded, posemo_postfunded, posemo_consequent, agency_baseline, etc... in order to use lm()? Or is there a better way to feed this into lm()?

Here is my current data structure:

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  name      stage       posemo  agency
  <chr>       <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a         prefunded    3.12   3.11
2 b         prefunded    3.07   2.23
3 b         consequent   3.28   3.84
4 b         postfunded   2.04   2.36
5 a         baseline     3.62   4.28
6 a         consequent   3.31   3.77
7 a         postfunded   3.5    4.54
8 b         baseline     2.84   4.11
```

Expected output would be to transform the DF in columns with:

```
name, posemo_baseline, posemo_prefunded, posemo_postfunded, posemo_consequent, agency_baseline, agency_prefunded, agency_postfunded, agency_consequent
```

Then I would run lm for each of the four stages on agency and posemo, eg, lm(posemo_baseline ~ agency_baseline, data = x), lm(posemo_prefunded ~ agency_prefunded, data = x), etc?

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: you don't need to reshape. You can do something like `lapply(split(x, x$state), function(dd) lm(posemo ~agency, data=dd))`. Because really you just want to run 4 different linear models.

Comment: @akrun, the expected output would be to transform the DF in columns with: name, posemo_baseline, posemo_prefunded, posemo_postfunded, posemo_consequent, agency_baseline, agency_prefunded, agency_postfunded, agency_consequent. Then I would run lm for each of the four stages on agency and posemo, eg, lm(posemo_baseline ~ agency_baseline, data = x), lm(posemo_prefunded ~ agency_prefunded, data = x), etc.

Comment: @KevinT  Please update your post by `edit`ing

Comment: @MrFlick, ok, thanks, that makes sense. So I am breaking it into four DFs, one for each state, and then running lm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we can use the `subset=` argument of `lm` to pick out different subsets to use giving a list of lm objects, one per level of `stage`:

```
Map(function(lv) lm(posemo ~ agency, DF, subset = stage == lv), levels(DF$stage))
```

Of course with only two points per run we won't be able to estimate sigma but if the data shown here is just a subset of the actual data we should be able to do that.

If the focus is on coefficients then we could just run one lm nested within stage (but note this will used a pooled sigma rather than a separate sigma for each -- the coefficients will be the same though).

```
lm(posemo ~ stage/(1 + agency) - 1, DF)
```

We could also use nlme with pool = TRUE or pool = FALSE depending on whether we want to  calculate a pooled sigma or not.

```
library(nlme)
lmList(posemo ~ agency | stage, DF, pool = FALSE)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "  name      stage       posemo  agency
1 a         prefunded    3.12   3.11
2 b         prefunded    3.07   2.23
3 b         consequent   3.28   3.84
4 b         postfunded   2.04   2.36
5 a         baseline     3.62   4.28
6 a         consequent   3.31   3.77
7 a         postfunded   3.5    4.54
8 b         baseline     2.84   4.11"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, colClasses = list(name = "character"))
```